# Картинка не подгружается при перезагрузке страницы || React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux

У меня есть компонент в котором при его запуске обновляются, и загружаются данные из state. Картинка которая подгружается в данном компоненте - уникальная, и берется из отдельной папки по индексу(который в свою очередь берется из state). При запуске этого компонента по задумке(то есть нажать на кнопку "перейти на страницу") все работает нормально, только я перезагружаю страницу, как мне выдает ошибку про подгрузку неизвестного модуля. Скрин оставлю тут -

[image: Error]

Comment: Без кода вам врятли смогут помочь, пожалуйста, выложите код в любую из js песочниц и закрепите ссылку в вопросе.

Comment: @Ceri я могу прикрепить скрины кода, или нужно именно в текстовом варианте?